# Fulltext search (sql server 2005) works only on some fields

Tags: sql-server-2005, unicode, full-text-search, nvarchar, freetext

OK this is the situation..

I am enabling fulltext search on a table but it only works on some fields..

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [defaultcatalog]
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_staticid on static(id)
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON static(title_gr LANGUAGE 19,title_en,description_gr LANGUAGE 19,description_en) KEY INDEX staticid ON [defaultcatalog] WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
```

now why the following will bring results

```
Select * from static where freetext(description_en, N'str')
```

and this not (while the both have text with str in it ..)

```
Select * from static where freetext(description_gr, N'str')
```

(i have tried it also without the language specification - greek in this case)
(the collation is of the database is Greek_CI_AS)
btw

```
Select * from static where description_gr like N'%str%'
```

will work just fine ..

all fields are nvarchar type and the _gr fields hold english and greek text..(should not matter)

All help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trying to figure out what's going on: what do you get with this query here?

```
SELECT * FROM static WHERE FREETEXT(*, N'str')
```

If you're not explicitly specifying any column to search in - does it give you the expected results?

Another point: I think you have a wrong language ID in your statement. According to SQL Server Books Online:

> When specified as a string,
>   language_term corresponds to the alias
>   column value in the syslanguages
>   system table. The string must be
>   enclosed in single quotation marks, as
>   in 'language_term'. **When specified
>   as an integer, language_term is the
>   actual LCID** that identifies the
>   language.

and from what I found on the internet searching around, the LCID for Greek is 1032 - not 19. Can you try with 1032 instead of 19? Does that make a difference?

Marc

Comment: If i run your command while i have the different languages defined for each field i get 
<pre>Full-text table or indexed view has more than one LCID among its full-text indexed columns.</pre>
if i run in while all fieldσ take default language it returns nothing .. weird, is in not ?

Comment: LCID 1032 says it is not installed (while i can see that the one with id 19 has LCID 1032)

text version is not working ..

Comment: Ok.. error on my first comment ...

When i Run the FREETEXT( *, N'str') while the language in the fullindex is the default, the selection will select whatever rows have the 'str' in the _en version ...

Comment: What if you use "GREEK" as the alias for the language, instead of 19 or 1032? E.g.  CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON static(title_gr LANGUAGE GREEK,  and so on?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply..

Actually it seems that FREETEXT either has issues with small words, and also it seems to have issues with the word breaking rules and it messes up most searches in greek text.. 

Thanks for your help ..